# __unsafe_unretained for a delegate won't build

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have this code (snippet) from a .h file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "ILView.h"

/**
 * Controls the orientation of the picker
 */
typedef enum {
    ILHuePickerViewOrientationHorizontal     =   0,
    ILHuePickerViewOrientationVertical       =   1
} ILHuePickerViewOrientation;

@class ILHuePickerView;

/**
 * Hue picker delegate
 */
@protocol ILHuePickerViewDelegate

/**
 * Called when the user picks a new hue
 *
 * @param hue 0..1 The hue the user picked
 * @param picker The picker used
 */
-(void)huePicked:(float)hue picker:(ILHuePickerView *)picker;

@end

/**
 * Displays a gradient allowing the user to select a hue
 */
@interface ILHuePickerView : ILView {
    id<ILHuePickerViewDelegate> delegate;
    float hue;
    ILHuePickerViewOrientation pickerOrientation;
}

/**
 * Delegate
 */
//@property (assign, nonatomic) IBOutlet id<ILHuePickerViewDelegate> delegate;
@property (assign, nonatomic) IBOutlet __unsafe_unretained id<ILHuePickerViewDelegate> delegate;

/**
 * The current hue
 */
@property (assign, nonatomic) float hue;
```

The .m file looks like this:

```
#import "ILHuePickerView.h"
#import "UIColor+GetHSB.h"

@interface ILHuePickerView(Private)

-(void)handleTouches:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;

@end

@implementation ILHuePickerView

@synthesize color, delegate, hue, pickerOrientation;

#pragma mark - Setup

-(void)setup
{
    [super setup];
```

I looked on SO for similar cases, and saw that I needed to put "__unsafe_unretained" in the property... I did that (hopefully correct), but it still fails on the build.  The full error message is:  Existing ivar 'delegate' for property 'delegate' with  assign attribute must be __unsafe_unretained

[image: Screenshot]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: As it is good question I up voted.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

As the error message is telling you, the *ivar*:

```
@interface ILHuePickerView : ILView {
    id<ILHuePickerViewDelegate> delegate;    // <-- This is the ivar
```

needs to be declared `__unsafe_unretained`:

```
__unsafe_unretained id<ILHuePickerViewDelegate> delegate;
```

not the property:

```
@property (assign, nonatomic) IBOutlet id<ILHuePickerViewDelegate> delegate;
```

because the ARC ownership qualifiers don't apply to properties; they only apply to variables.

Since the `@synthesize` directive *creates* the ivar for you (with the correct ARC qualifier), however, you can just skip its declaration:

```
@interface ILHuePickerView : ILView 

/**
 * Delegate
 */
@property (assign, nonatomic) IBOutlet id<ILHuePickerViewDelegate> delegate;

// etc.
```

Which is, in fact, now the *recommended* procedure; see [Defining Classes](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocDefiningClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH12-TPXREF122) in TOCPL.

Comment: Thank you... I tried commenting the @property, but that didn't work, so I just added __unsafe_unretained to the declaration... cleaned up the build for that error... thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I've used ILColorPicker in the past, and it is definitely not ARC ready.  Set 
`-fno-objC-arc` in the compiler flag settings for the ILColorPicker classes.