# Xcode ARC conflicts with overlayviewcontroller

Tags: xcode, automatic-ref-counting

[PhotoPicker sample code uses an overlay view](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/PhotoPicker/Listings/OverlayViewController_h.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010196-OverlayViewController_h-DontLinkElementID_7). Below is some relevant code from PhotoPicker that I am using in my app, but I want to use **ARC**, and PhotoPicker does not use ARC. I think I have managed to workaround the other conflicts between PhotoPicker and ARC, but not this one.

When in `OverlayViewController.h` I use the line below `id <OverlayViewControllerDelegate> delegate;` as is, I get the error `Existing ivar 'delegate' for property 'delegate' with  assign attribute must be __unsafe_unretained`.

OverlayViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioServices.h>

@protocol OverlayViewControllerDelegate;

@interface OverlayViewController : UIViewController <UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate>
{
    id <OverlayViewControllerDelegate> delegate;  // **THIS IS THE KEY LINE**
}    

@property (nonatomic, assign) id <OverlayViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImagePickerController *imagePickerController;

- (void)setupImagePicker:(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType)sourceType;

@end

@protocol OverlayViewControllerDelegate
- (void)didTakePicture:(UIImage *)picture;
- (void)didFinishWithCamera;
@end
```

[But when I follow the advise here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10080312/unsafe-unretained-for-a-delegate-wont-build), and either comment out that line or prepend that line with `__unsafe_unretained`, I get the issue `Cannot find protocol declaration for 'OverlayViewControllerDelegate'; did you mean 'UISplitViewControllerDelegate'?` in `MyViewController.h`.

MyViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#import "OverlayViewController.h"

@interface MyViewController : UIViewController <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, OverlayViewControllerDelegate>
@end
```

Answer (score 0):

There was an error in my question. Very sorry.
In the actual code somehow the `#import "OverlayViewController.h` had been omitted.

```
MyViewController.h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#import "OverlayViewController.h"
```