# existing instance variable delegate for property delegate with assign attribute must be unsafe_unretained

Tags: iphone, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, xcode4.5

Getting error that on

```
@protocol TapDetectingImageViewDelegate;

@interface TapDetectingImageView : UIImageView {
id <TapDetectingImageViewDelegate> tapDelegate;

@property (nonatomic, assign) id <TapDetectingImageViewDelegate> tapDelegate;

@synthesize tapDelegate;
```

Tried everything like

```
 _weak id <TapDetectingImageViewDelegate> tapDelegate;

 @property (weak) id <TapDetectingImageViewDelegate> tapDelegate;
```

and even tried this also

```
_unsafe_unretained id <TapDetectingImageViewDelegate> tapDelegate;

@property (_unsafe_unretained) id <TapDetectingImageViewDelegate> tapDelegate;
```

even tried removing instance variable definition as synthesize takes care of it when using ARC mode.

But still nothing is working to remove this error.

If anyone can help me to solve this error.

Thanks.

Comment: It's `__weak`, not `_weak`

Comment: i changed that but still getting error

Comment: i had to clean it and then analyze it again error is gone now. Big thanks to you. I was going crazy for this.

Comment: that error is back again. I wonder what is going on

Comment: Have you tried this version: @property (weak) id <TapDetectingImageViewDelegate> tapDelegate; along with eliminating the ivar and the @synthesize? That's the standard way, and should work (probably should add nonatomic to the declaration as well).

Comment: i should remove @synthesize tapDelegate; also. then getting error use of undeclared identifier tapDelegate

Comment: Use `self.tapDelegate` instead.

Comment: removed ivar and synthesize and now its working.

Comment: Don't subclass UIImageView to do this. Use a UIGestureRecognizer. Composition over inheritance...

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to Obj-C, I found this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/10080387/3867557
and your code should look like:

```
@protocol TapDetectingImageViewDelegate;
@interface TapDetectingImageView : UIImageView 
@property (nonatomic, assign) id <TapDetectingImageViewDelegate> tapDelegate;
```

Hope it help.